# C++ function overloading cannot identify char

Tags: c++

When I input two integers, the output is correctly their difference. However when I enter a string and a char, instead of returning how many times the char appears in the string, it returns -1, which is the out put for error. Could anyone please help me? It's just my second day learing c++...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

void mycount(int a, int b)
{
        std::cout<< a - b <<std::endl;
}

void mycount(char str[], char s[])
{
        int len,i;
        int sum=0;

        len = strlen(str);
        for (i=0;i<len;i++){
            if (strncmp(&str[i],&s[0],1) == 0){
            sum = sum + 1;

};
};
printf("results: %d times\n",sum);
}

int main()
{
        int a,b;
        char c[200],d;
        if(std::cin>> a >> b){
            mycount(a,b);
        }
        if(std::cin>> c[200] >> d){
            mycount(a,b);
        }
        else{
            std::cout<< "-1" <<std::endl;
        }
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.sync();
}
```

Comment: Why are trying to extract something from `cin` to `c[200]`? It's out of bounds. My best guess is that you are inputting an entire string whereas `c[200]` is just one `char`. The `eof` flag will be set and `cin` will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @JorenHeit write a program that provides two overloaded function named mycount(). This function either cumputes the difference between the first and second parameter if integers are passed or counts the number of occurrences of a charatcter if a string and character is passed.

Comment: You never pass a string

Answer (score 0):

Hint - what will this program print?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char c[200],d;

    cout << sizeof(c) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(d) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer:

200

1

That declaration does not do what you think it does - c is an array of 200 chars, d is a single char. It's a *feature* of the C declaration syntax, same as:

```
int *c, d;
```

c is a pointer to int, d is an int.

Since you are doing C++, why not make your life easier and use std::string instead?

Answer (score 0):

A few changes should fix your problems. First when inputting an array with `cin` use `getline` and call `ignore` right before hand. I find it easier to pass s as a char instead of an array of size one make sure your call your second my count with c and d instead of a and b.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

void mycount(int a, int b)
{
        std::cout<< a - b <<std::endl;
}

void mycount(char str[], char s)
{
        int len,i;
        int sum=0;

        len = strlen(str);
        for (i=0;i<len;i++){
            if (strncmp(&str[i],&s,1) == 0){
            sum = sum + 1;

};
};
printf("results: %d times\n",sum);
}

int main()
{
        int a,b;
        char c[200],d;
        if(std::cin>> a >> b){
            mycount(a,b);
        }
         std::cin.ignore();
        if(std::cin.getline (c,200) && std::cin >> d){
            mycount(c,d);
        }
        else{
            std::cout<< "-1" <<std::endl;
        }
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.sync();
}
```

These changes should fix it.